# PHP insert tamil excel data into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert excel data into mysql table.Its is working fine with english words.But when i am using other languages my code is reading as some other characters.Here is my code to get excel datas.

```
$inputFileName = './Questions/' . $questionfile;

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->toArray(null, true, true, true);

$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);
```

After that I am getting the A cell value by the below foreach.

```
foreach ($allDataInSheet as $value) {
    $question[] = trim($value["A"]);
}
```

When I print $question by var_dump($question) it is displaying as some special characters.Please help me to fix this.(I am using tamil letters in excel)

Comment: And you're using UTF-8 throughout?

Comment: you have change the character set of database to insert tamil language.

Comment: header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); I am using this line at top

Comment: but before inserting into table I have to get the values from excel.While reading from excel values are displayed as some special characters

Comment: @SaravananMurugesan   //.While reading from excel values are displayed as some special characters //  Check whether Excel file is saved in Unicode encoding. Also, you may need to tell the code that your content(excel) is in Unicode encoding